# Making horizontal to a vertical list without removing Display:Inline / Inline-Block

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a fluid website for all devices with Html/Css. I cannot figure out a way to make my navigation horizontal without removing a display property. I cannot figure out a way to turn the navigation items back to their vertical form this is my code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <a href="index.html"> <li>HOME</li></a>
          <br>
          <br>
          <a href="lessons.html"><li>LESSONS</li></a>
          <br>
        </ul>
     </nav>
```

CSS (mobile):

```
nav ul li {
  background-color:#0066FF;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff; 
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

RESPONSIVE CSS (desktop):

```
.about nav ul li {
    clear: both;
  }
```

I tried to clear both sides of the list items to try to make the list items vertical, but obviously didn't work.

Comment: Can you make a snippet please?

Comment: I tried the <br> tags, they only mess with the mobile version.

Comment: Apart from your invalid HTML code (and the use of `br` elements where you should be using CSS as well to specify margins/paddings instead) – why are you set against changing CSS property values if you _want_ to achieve a different formatting? That makes no sense IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/ronansmith/vqk68ucu/

You should put `<a>` inside the <`li>`, not the way you're doing it now. Cuz `<li>` always follows the `<ul>`